# Incorporate Git command in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My task is to pull code from Bitbucket and check whether there are any new files commited or any files modified from last commit. If any chamges are available I need to copy the file name and path to a .csv files. Below commmand will check the diff and copy to .csv files. But same activity needs to happen via Jenkinsfile pipeline.

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M @~ > list.csv`

Jenkinsfile script:-

```
#!groovy
void Download_Repositories(){
      checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
        extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'code']],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@bitbucket.org:org-dev/master.git',
        credentialsId:'service-user']]
      ])
}
pipeline {
    agent { label 'LABEL' }
//    triggers { pollSCM('*/5 * * * *') }
  stages {
      stage('Download Repositories') {
        steps {
            Download_Repositories()
            sh '''
            ls -ltr code/playbooks/
            git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M @~ > list.csv
            '''
          }
        }

   }//stages
}//pipeline
```

Error:-

```
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing checkout in code directory so you need to use code directory as your working directory. By default all steps are running into project workspace.

You can use `dir` to change the working directory see below example:

```
steps{
    Download_Repositories()
    dir("${WORKSPACE}/code"){
        sh '''
            ls -ltr code/playbooks/
            git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M @~ > list.csv
            '''
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting below error:- `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M @~
fatal: ambiguous argument '@~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]' `